# How can I cover a large posterboard with glitter?

Tags: paper, tool-selection, cardboard

I have a 22"x28" posterboard that I'd like to cover in glitter. What can I use to get the glitter to stick to the posterboard?

Comment: Posterboard is a name that can be used for a few different materials, it's most commonly thick card, but it some people call foamcore and corrigated plastic core boards posterboards too. Can you elaborate on what exactly it is you have? And if it is simply heavy paper/card, do you know what weight it is?

Comment: Heavy paper/card. The usual stuff you buy at an office supply store.

Comment: Thanks, in that case Rhonda's answer below might be the best bet, other liquid glues would likely be too heavy and are more likely to warp your card on you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the poster to be solid glitter, not simply speckled, I would use a **spray adhesive**, which is best with large surfaces. It also will not add additional weight or bow the the poster like a liquid or paste glue.

Spray adhesive and glitter are extremely messy. Work outside with plenty of ground cover (I suggest paper) and a large over-spray zone (don't spray near cars, etc.).

I recommend working the entire surface of the poster at once and not in sections. Previously glittered sections will get over-spray and you'll end up with sections of the poster with thicker layers of glitter than others.

The key to doing the whole poster will be to follow the directions on the spray glue can and to get a good solid covering of glue on the entire surface before applying glitter.

You'll need to literally dump a pile of glitter on the sticky poster, pick up the poster and shake the glitter around like you're shifting for gold. When the surface seems covered, turn the poster up facing you and tap the bottom edge a couple of times on the ground to release extra glitter. You should get a good view as to how well it's covered.

**Above all**, test your technique! Get a second poster, cut it in quarters, and begin testing your technique until it works the way you want.

Comment: Given the potential for microplastic pollution from the glitter, and for wind blowing away the glue unevenly, I'd do it *in*doors, using lots of scrap card or plastic sheet to protect the workspace, then you could vacuum up the split glitter. You'd want decent ventilation still, but not a direct draught

Answer (score 1):

I use glitter blast spray paint that can be found at Walmart you do repeated thin coats letting it dry between each coat ! And before you try the glitter blast you can mix them glitter and the clear Elmer's glue and brush it over your poster board then after its tried a day apply glitter blast

Answer (score -2):

You can get stick glue and put it on there, and then just dump your desired amount of glitter on the board before the glue dries.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many glue sticks would I need to cover a 22x28" sheet?

Comment: I would say more than 10 maybe 15 or 20 but if I had that size poster board I would actually be able to tell you. I would say use liquid glue, but if you do it may become very, very messy.

Comment: In my experience glue sticks (like pritt stick) run the risk of the surface not being even and they can dry out and glitter can fall off as they are not very permanent - you'd want a good high quality glue and would need to test out spread and sticking power a day or two later when it's dried.