# Glitter trifold poster board

Tags: tool-selection

I am trying to help my daughter with a school project. The topic is space. She would like to use a black trifold poster board to present her project on but is trying to figure out how to create a shimmery/glitter effect all over the board. She wants it to resemble a starry night. Any suggestions on how to create this effect on a trifold poster board?

Comment: https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/how-can-i-cover-a-large-posterboard-with-glitter?rq=1